# PHP: looking to query if email is unique, then if so, query to add the record to database

Tags: php, mysql

Am not experienced, so appreciate any help.

Am looking to build a PHP to confirm that registration of user has a unique email address. If unique, then to add to sql database, and echo out respective value.

This is what I have - the echo value is produced if the email address is duplicate, but the echo value is not produced and the db not updated if it's unique.

```
<?php
$email= $_GET["email"];
$firstname = $_GET["firstname"];
$lastname = $_GET["lastname"];

$con = mysql_connect("user","db","pass");
mysql_select_db("db");

$query1 = "SELECT * FROM `db` WHERE `Email` = '$email'";

$result = mysql_query($query1);



if ( mysql_num_rows ($result) == 1 )
{$value="Already registered";

}
else
{
 mysql_query("INSERT INTO db (Email, FirstName, LastName) VALUES ('$email','$firstname','$lastname')");
mysql_close($con);

$value="Confirmed";


}

echo $value;
```

Comment: how is jQuery related to this question?

Comment: By the way `SELECT count(*)` much faster than `SELECT *`

Comment: `INSERT IGNORE` FTW! http://www.tutorialspoint.com/mysql/mysql-handling-duplicates.htm

Comment: You're open to SQL injection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of getting all rows, take only one of them like this. It will save lots of memory.

```
$query1 = "SELECT 1 FROM `db` WHERE `Email` = '$email' LIMIT 1";
```

Then the following line

```
if ( mysql_num_rows ($result) == 1 )
```

will be logically correct. Otherwise if there are 2 or more records in the database, the result is false. With my fix this `if` will be logical.

The other solution would be to select the number of the rows, but since the emails are to be unique in the database, there is no point doing something like

```
$query1 = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `db` WHERE `Email` = '$email'";
```

However this way, instead of checking the amount of rows in the result, you can check the result without fearing it being empty. But again, since your database's logic is to have one email only once, there is no point checking how many of them there are since the result will be either 0 or 1 :)

Comment: Understand the logic, makes sense. Aciu...;)

Comment: Please vote up and mark as answer if this helped :) Prašom :)

Answer (score 0):

1. make sure your code not give any error
2. as  your if condition

   if ( mysql_num_rows ($result) == 1 )

that means if you have a more then `>1` recoded it `false` so change it to

```
if ( mysql_num_rows ($result) >0 )
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$query1 = mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(*) AS num FROM `db` WHERE `Email` = '$email'");
$result = mysql_fetch_assoc($query1);

if ($result['num'] == 1)
{
   // already registered
}
else
{

}
```

Also you've completely forgot about sql injection. You need to ensure all values supplied by the user are safe to run through the database. You can do this using mysql_real_escape_string(). i.e:

```
$email = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['email']);
```

Answer (score 0):

To solve this problem I would use Ajax:

php **check_email.php**

```
$email= $_POST["email"];
$firstname = $_GET["firstname"];
$lastname = $_GET["lastname"];
...
$query1 = "SELECT * FROM `db` WHERE `Email` = '$email'";
$result = mysql_query($query1);
if (mysql_num_rows ($result)){
  echo "yes";
} else {
  mysql_query("INSERT INTO db (Email, FirstName, LastName) VALUES ('$email','$firstname','$lastname')");
  echo "no";
}
```

**HTML**:

```
    <form method="post" action=""/>
      <input name="email" type="text" id="email" value=""/>
      <input name="firstname" type="text" id="firstname" value=""/>
      <input name="lastname" type="text" id="lastname" value=""/>
      <input name="Submit" type="button" id="submit" value="Go"/>
      <div id="msg"></div>
    </form>
    <!--load latest version of jquery-->
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script>
    //JS (use jquery):
    $("#submit").click(function () {
        $.ajax({
          type: "POST",
          url: "check_email.php",
          dataType: "text",
          //send data to php
          data: {email:$("#email").val(),firstname:$("#firstname").val(),lastname:$("#lastname").val()},
          //get answers
          success: function (response) {
            if(responce=="yes") $("#msg").html("email exists!")
            else if (responce=="no") $("#msg").html("Email was successfully added to the database!")
          },
          error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
            alert(xhr.status);
            alert(thrownError);
          }
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Works great up until success: function(response). For some reason can't get the echo response to be translated into the #msg div. And fixed typo from responce to response.

Comment: Sorry, you need to write `$_POST["firstname"]` instead `$_GET["firstname"]` and `$_POST"lastname"]` instead `$_GET["lastname"]`

Comment: you can also write `alert(response)` after `success: function (response) {...`  to see what php returns...