# Check for unique e-mail & Restrict upload file type to PDF

Tags: php, email, pdf

I am trying to make a code to submit a form with email and attach a pdf file. I have made e-mail column as unique in the database, but from front end it shows as the file was uploaded(although the record is not saved).I have also used allowed ext in the code, but it doesnt work. below is the code i am using. Request to modify the code for me. Thanks ahead.

```
<?php
include_once 'dbconfig.php';
if(isset($_POST['btn-upload']))
{    
     $name = trim($_POST["uname"]);
     $email = trim($_POST["uemail"]);
     $exp = trim($_POST["uexp"]);
     $desig = trim($_POST["udesig"]);
     $tech = trim($_POST["utech"]); 

    $file = rand(1000,100000)."-".$_FILES['file']['name'];
    $file_loc = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];
    $file_size = $_FILES['file']['size'];
    $file_type = $_FILES['file']['type'];
    $allowed_ext = 'application/pdf';
    $folder="uploads/";


    // new file size in KB
    $new_size = $file_size/1024;  
    // new file size in KB

    // make file name in lower case
    $new_file_name = strtolower($file);
    // make file name in lower case

    $final_file=str_replace(' ','-',$new_file_name);
    if($allowed_ext != $allowed_ext)
            {
                echo "Warning: Please upload your note in PDF file type only";
                unlink($fileTmpLoc);
                exit();
            }
            else

            if(move_uploaded_file($file_loc,$folder.$final_file))

    {

        $sql="INSERT INTO tbl_uploads(name,email,exp,desig,tech,file,type,size) VALUES('$name','$email','$exp','$desig','$tech','$final_file','$file_type','$new_size')";
        mysql_query($sql);
        ?>
        <script>

        window.location.href='success.php';
        </script>
        <?php
    }
    else
    {
        ?>
        <script>
        alert('error while uploading file');
        window.location.href='index.php?fail';
        </script>
        <?php
    }
}

?>
```

Comment: your code is deprecated use PDO or SQLi instead, also if you want to keep your code check if sql_query was sucessfull $result = mysql_query($sql);
if (!$result) {
    die('Invalid query: ' . mysql_error());
}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace:

```
if($allowed_ext != $allowed_ext)
        {
            echo "Warning: Please upload your note in PDF file type only";
            unlink($fileTmpLoc);
            exit();
        }
```

with:

```
if($file_type != $allowed_ext)
        {
            echo "Warning: Please upload your note in PDF file type only";
            unlink($fileTmpLoc);
            exit();
        }
```

Comment: Dear Abhijeet, The correction for file type works. can you please let me know how to write the code for unique e-mail. I tried
$sql = "SELECT COUNT(*) AS count from tbl_users where email = :email_id";
  try {
    $stmt = $DB->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->bindValue(":email_id", $email);
    $stmt->execute();
    $result = $stmt->fetchAll();
 
    if ($result[0]["count"] > 0) {
      $msg = "Email already exist";
      $msgType = "warning";
    } else {
      $sql = "INSERT INTO `tbl_uploads
but this gives server error. and code doesnot work. can you let me know how to use this in above code?

Comment: hi, can you give me code from $sql... where should it be inserted. i tried repalcing :email with $email but doesnot work.

Comment: This query works for me: SELECT COUNT( * ) AS count
FROM tbl_users
WHERE email = 'sample@gmail.com'

Comment: Can you try print_r($result);
 with your initial code?

Comment: now i tried using:
$query = "SELECT COUNT(*) AS count from tbl_uploads where email = '$email'";  
     $result = mysql_query($query);
if ( mysql_num_rows ($result)==1 )
             {echo "Warning: Email already exists";
                unlink($fileTmpLoc);
                exit();
             }
        else
This code is giving warning even if the email doesnot exist.

Comment: Can you use your initial code and print the query result using print_r($result); ?

Comment: for the current code it gives
Resource id #4Warning: Email already exists
it is strange that if i put ...if ( mysql_num_rows ($result)==100...then the record gets saved

Comment: it is strange that if i put ...if ( mysql_num_rows ($result)==2 or anything other than 0& 1...then the record gets saved

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/95893/discussion-between-abhijith-s-j-and-ranjit).

Answer (score 0):

use `pathinfo` to get file extentions

```
$ext = pathinfo($filename, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);

if($ext != "pdf") {
      //error part here
}
```

for email part, before checking file extension, write query like this,

```
select * from your_table where email = "{$_POST['email']}".
```

id num rows of above query is more than 0, then email is already present in your database,

Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12367827/php-looking-to-query-if-email-is-unique-then-if-so-query-to-add-the-record-to) for unique email part.

Answer (score 0):

Extension is the chars after dot.

you can get it by pathname:

```
$ext = pathinfo($_FILES['file']['name'], PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
```

and then you allowed extention should be :

```
$allowed_ext = 'pdf';
```

compare it like this:

```
if($allowed_ext == $ext){ ...
```